# Multiple buttons in footer in Ionic 3

Tags: button, ionic-framework, footer, ionic3

I am trying to add two buttons (left and right) in the footer section in Ionic 3 project. Either its coming side by side or in two different row. Following is my code.

```
<ion-footer>
  <ion-buttons text-start>
    <button ion-button clear (click)="backPage()">Back</button>
  </ion-buttons>
  <ion-buttons text-end>
    <button ion-button clear (click)="nextPage()">Next</button>
  </ion-buttons>
</ion-footer>
```

Following is the result

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ion-footer no-border text-center>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-buttons left>
            <button ion-button icon-only clear large (click)="formSlider.slideTo(0)">
                <ion-icon name="skip-backward"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-buttons right>
            <button ion-button icon-only clear large (click)="formSlider.slideTo(formSlider.length() - 1)">
                <ion-icon name="skip-forward"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-buttons>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `<ion-buttons start>` or `<ion-buttons end>`

```
<ion-footer>
<ion-toolbar>
<ion-buttons start>
  <button ion-button (click)="func1()"> Back
  </button>
</ion-buttons>

<ion-buttons end>
  <button ion-button (click)="func2()"> Next
  </button>
</ion-buttons>
</ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```